# Getting widget hierarchy with Appium for Android

Tags: android, appium

I am a newbie in Appium. I am trying to read the screen of my android application in a certain moment and get a hierarchical view of all the AndroidElements that are shown in the screen (similar to what the Appium inspector shows). This means that I wanna be able to tell which AndroidElements are inside a certain other AndroidElement (such as a ListView).

I am able to get the AndroidElements in the screen using

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector()")
```

but i am not able to derive the hierarchy of the widgets. I tried to call

```
element.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector()")
```

on a certain AndroidElement hoping to get all its children but it seems it is not the case.

How do I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Install Android SDK and then navigate to link c:\users\\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools you'll notice a batch file with name 'uiautomatorviewer.bat'. Double click on it to launch "Uiautomatorviewer" GUI.

1. Check if is your Android device correctly connected ($ adb devices)
2. Start your app and go to screen which one you try to read
3. Then click on second option from menu to the right from folder picture

Uiautomatorviewer generate hierarchy for you.

Watchout appium server must be turn off.

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to do it programmatically. I am building a GUI testing tool therefore I need to read the GUI (and its hierarchy) in order to interact with it.